# Novice: Display the JSON data from url in Android the right way

Tags: android, json

I'm having some trouble getting the json data from url into android as a string.
I've read and trying multiple tutorials on getting the json data from url and it worked, however, this time  the json I want to get from the url is like the sample below

```
{
    "return": [
        {
            "id": "1", 
            "message": "random", 
            "name": "n1"
        }, 
        {
            "id": "11", 
            "message": "a", 
            "name": "koko"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see , the json data above seems simple to get however, when I use the sample code to get the data, I keep failing at getting the json. I'm quite new to android and I find it hard to find which part of the code have some mistakes. Are there some minor mistake with the code below ?

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

    // Getting JSON Array node
    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("return");

    // looping through All Contacts
    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

        String id = c.getString("id");
        String name = c.getString("name");
        String message = c.getString("message");

        Log.d("id: ", "> " + id);
        Log.d("name: ", "> " + name);
        Log.d("message: ", "> " + message);

    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}

} else {
     Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
}
```

Comment: try to post logcat ?

Comment: I tried to just post logcat to confirm if the data was retrieved, nothing more.

Comment: What is problem is there?? please show an error.

Comment: I get this error "11-21 14:11:39.350: W/System.err(595):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)"